# Android network configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to set my network configuration. The problem is that after I set the properties of configuration and call `addNetwork()` method, the return value (configuration id) is `-1`. I do not know what's wrong with my code. I have used the same code in another project and it works correctly.

These are the permissions I used:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

the full code

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val wifiManager = activity.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
    val networkAccessPoint = NetworkAccessPoint.getInstance(wifiManager)

    networkAccessPoint.generateConfigurationAccessPoint()

    return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
}
```

NetwockAccessPoint class

```
public void generateConfigurationAccessPoint(){

    WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = getWifiConfiguration();
    String SSID = getSSID();
    wifiConfiguration.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", SSID);
    wifiConfiguration.preSharedKey = "\"password\"";
    wifiConfiguration.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
    wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
    wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
    wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
    wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
    wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
    wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);

    int networkConfigurationId = mWifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration);

    mWifiManager.enableNetwork(networkConfigurationId, true);
    setWifiConfiguration(wifiConfiguration);
    setWifiAPEnabled(wifiConfiguration, true);
}
```

The code doesn't throw any exceptions.

**SOLVED**

I got the error what i did ... i wanted to create access point with hotspot so that i do not need `addNetwork() enableNetwork() setConfiguration()`  .... and i had got value -1 wifi was off
(As i mentioned before i wanted AP for hotspot).

Comment: What is the api level of the device?

Comment: @TonyKutzler min api 21

Comment: I mean what is it on the device/emulator your testing with?

Comment: api ( 21-22-23)